# How do I execute an action which doesn't return anything in parallel for every item in a sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

This piece of code applies an action in parallel to every element of a sequence:

```
import multiprocessing

...
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
print(pool.map(action, sequence))
```

How do I run an action in parallel while ignoring its result (or if it doesn't return anything)? Do I need to do it like in the piece of code below—which works but doesn't look right to me—or is there a more elegant method?

```
import multiprocessing

...
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
list(pool.map(action, sequence))) # Don't assign the result to a variable, since
                                  # it will be just a list of `None`.
```

In other words, how do I do this, but in parallel:

```
for c in sequence:
    action(c)
```

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool.map` patterns itself off of the `map` function but the comparison only goes so far. Although many would consider it bad form to run `map` for its side effects, its normal to do so with a Pool. And even though python 3's `map` returns an iterator, `Pool.map` returns a list. So, you don't even need to "listize" it. `pool.map(action, sequence))` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only standard solution for dumping away the result is by assigning to the throwaway `_` name:

```
_ = pool.map(action, sequence)
```

Apart from that, a trick I've seen is hiding the call inside another function which in essence hides the result from you, that is:

```
def applypool(p, action, sequence):
    list(p.map(action, sequence))
```